# Eclipse/Minecraft error when importing gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I have been trying to set up a workspace in order to make some basic mods for Minecraft 1.12.2, and I have been following this guide in order to do so: https://codakid.com/guide-to-minecraft-modding-with-java/

I had some issues when trying to run the build, but fixed them by following this guide about the eclipse set-up: https://techwiseacademy.com/minecraft-modding-setting-up-your-environment-in-windows-10-minecraft-16-4/

I know that there are major differences between the two versions, but somehow it worked.
I managed to get Minecraft to start, but crashed in the middle for some reason, and I decided to try to do everything again from scratch, but now, whenever I import the Gradle project, I keep getting error the following error: [image]
Now whatever I try, whether to switch to 1.8 JRE, change the compiler, this keeps happening.

*A note that I should add: the first time it worked, the importing took some time to complete, but after trying again, happens much faster.

Does anyone have any idea why this keeps happening, after working once? I looked around different sites for similar problems, but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a possible solution for all this: I believe the Gradle Daemon is tempering somehow with all this, or at the very minimum bigs it (simply: previous daemon gives error.

To fix this, you need to delete the ".gradle"  folder on two locations:

1. The place where the MDK folder is: [image]
2. In your "user home" folder (It should be at: C:\Users"UserNameHere")[image]